# Error:DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case (1, 2, 1, 0)

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am building an RL agent for which the model is defined:

```
def build_model(states, actions):
    azioni = list(actions)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(azioni)]))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
return model
```

The `action.space` is:

```
self.action_space=gym.spaces.Tuple(tuple([gym.spaces.Discrete(3)]*4))
```

My action space consists of 4 actions for 4 agents, where agents is a list of 4 object agents.

Then define Agent:

```
def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy,
                   nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
return dqn
```

When I try to build the agent:

```
dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-98-512746ffa1dc> in <module>
11     return dqn
12 
---> 13 dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
14 dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
15 dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)

<ipython-input-98-512746ffa1dc> in build_agent(model, actions)
8     memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
9     dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy,
---> 10                   nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10,     target_model_update=1e-2)
11     return dqn
12 

~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rl/agents/dqn.py   in __init__(self, model, policy, test_policy, enable_double_dqn, enable_dueling_network,  dueling_type, *args, **kwargs)
109             raise ValueError('Model "{}" has more than one output. DQN expects a model that has a single output.'.format(model))
110         if tuple(model.output.shape) != list((None, self.nb_actions)):
--> 111             raise ValueError('Model output "{}" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case  {}.'.format(model.output, self.nb_actions))
112 
113         # Parameters.

ValueError: Model output "Tensor("dense_16/Relu:0", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float32)" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case (1, 2, 1, 0).
```

I checked the value of model.output.shape and action:

```
print(model.output_shape)
#(None, 4)

print(actions)
#(1, 2, 1, 0)
```

I don't know how to adapt the action list to pass to my agents with the `model.output_shape`. Since my `space_action` is given by a list where `space_action[0]` is the action of `agent[0]`, `action[1]` is the action of `agent[1]` etc.

Comment: This is a multiagent scenario I assume. Are you trying to build a centralized model (i.e one model that outputs the actions of all agents) or a decentralized model (each agent's model outputs the action for that specific agent). There are many variations.

Comment: I’m trying to build a centralized model, where stocks are issued for all agents.
I am a beginner.

Comment: It is going to be tough if you are a beginner. The difficulty is framing the problem as a MARL problem. I suggest you to take a look at this architecture and their paper in order to understand better how to set up our model. Also look at the MAPE env in the repository and the file world or game. From there you will understand how to set up your action space in order to be compatible with your model. Link here: https://github.com/marlbenchmark/on-policy

Comment: thank you very much, now look